# How can I show the image when the mouse hovers in an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find a way using jQuery and fancybox to show a picture when the mouse hovers on it. I know that there is the .hover but don't know how to use it.

This is how I show the image on click.

```
$("a#single_image").fancybox({              
'transitionIn'      : 'none',   
'transitionOut'     : 'none', 
'titlePosition' : 'over' 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For .hover(), you will want to put in two function, one for mouseover, and one when the mouse leaves.

```
$("a#single_image").hover(function() {
  $('#myImage').show('slow');
}, function() {
  $('#myImage').hide('slow');
});
```

Comment: I set the id of `a` to single_image (as it was) and the id of the image as myImage right? If so, it doesn't work...

Comment: Does it have anything to do that I set many images to myImage? If so how can I change it to class?

Comment: You should never have more than one element on a page with the same ID. If you want to do that, you should indeed switch them to classes. In jQuery, #id selects and ID and .class selects a class. So use $('.myImage') to select all images with class="myImage".